# Command not found in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, sed

the command

```
     sed -i  "/{/a $address" genesis.json
```

crashes with error

```
     sed: -e expression n°1, caractère 61: commande inconnue: `"'
```

using

```
 $c=abs
```

it works .

Do anyone have an idea about the problem?

Comment: Use a JSON-aware tool to edit json files, e.g. `jq`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?? Are you looking to replace address in `genesis.json` ?

Comment: no, I am trying to add $address in genesis.json after {